# Iterate through and delete empty HTML table rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to iterate through a HTML table using jQuery and delete empty rows. The page is driven by ASP.NET and with certain permission, items in the table will be hidden. Therefore, I wanted to create this script to remove the empty rows and get rid of the space between the other items that are still displayed. I cannot seem to get what I currently have to run and I am unsure as to why. Here is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr').each(function () {
            $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().trim() == "") {
                    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                };
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to handle server side?

Comment: Handling this server side depends on how the table is being rendered.  If the table is being generated dynamically, then modify the code to simply not "emit" the undesirable HTML.  If the table is being generated using a databound control, then you may need to modify the datasource.  If the table is static HTML in the page, then you may be stuck with a client side solution.

Comment: The table is static HTML and the page_load event determines what links populate the table... I know it is a bad way to do privileged navigation but I am stuck with it at this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code appears to work just fine.  Try running the following on its own to see what I mean:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Tests</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('tr').each(function () {
                $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text().trim() == "") {
                        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                    };
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>testing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>testing</td>
            <td>testing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>testing</td>
            <td>   </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Could there be something else on the page that might be conflicting?

Comment: In the question, the OP mentions that "and with certain permission, items in the table will be hidden".  I wonder if the cells aren't really empty, but instead styled with display:none, or something like that.

Comment: There is a page load event that hides the ASP hyperlink. In return, the ASPX page is produced with a blank cell. "<tr><td></td></tr>"

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browser are you testing this page with?  I just noticed that this code appears to fail in IE but works fine in FireFox.  After some playing around, it looks like IE is having issues with the trim() function within your conditional.  Try changing the conditional to use the following instead: $.trim($(this).text())

Comment: This code doesn't work and removes TR even if there is just one empty TD in TR.

Answer (score 3):

Lead to problem in case We have Only TD empty and all other TD is Filled

I'm change the Code to make this in its consideration

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('tr').each(function () {
                var totalTDs = $(this).find('td').length;
                var emptyTDS = 0;

                $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text().trim() == "") {
                        emptyTDS += 1;
                    };
                });

                if (emptyTDS == totalTDs) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Wonderful thanks _I know this is an old post, but this is a big time saver!_

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var td = $(this).find('td:empty');
if ( td.length > 0 ) $(this).remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

That said, you really want to do this on the server side. It'll look ugly on the client side because you'll have the empty rows messing things up until the document ready event is fired.

Comment: I like this shortened answer but when I run it, it still does not remove the space in between the buttons on my test page. I just have a table with two buttons, one at the top, one at the bottom and a lot of blank rows in between. I am running it locally, is that an issue?

Comment: I think this answer can be shortened to 1 line $('table').find('tr:empty').remove();

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer removes also non-empty rows. This code only removes the row if all row columns are empty.

```
// remove empty rows
$('.tr').each(function () {
    let remove = true;
    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().trim() !== "") {
            remove = false;
            return false;
        };
    });

    if (remove) $(this).remove();
});
```